# usage of __declspec(dllimport) in MS VS 2008

Tags: c, visual-c++

Suppose we have: mysolution.sln in MS VS 2008, under which say we have 2 projects:

1)
project1.vcproj
- Here we have project1_file1.cpp, in which we have function defined:

```
  doSomething(){
  ...
  }
```

2)
project2.vcproj
- Say, here we have project2_file1.h and project2_file1.c. What I am trying to achieve in project2_file1.c is something like this, where:

```
myJumpTable_t myJumpTable = {
   doSomething
};
```

I understand that we must have a struct defined somewhere:

```
 typedef struct _myJumpTable_t {
       void (*doSomething)();
}myJumpTable_t;
```

But I am not sure, where this must be declared? I am also aware that we must be using  __declspec(dllimport), again I am not sure how to use this. Please help me with this. I am stuck with this issue from many days.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, by default, no functions are exported from a DLL. You must manually export them either with a .map file, or `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Anything that you are importing from the DLL must be defined in more or less the same way it would be if it was just a normal part of the program, except the declaration must begin with `__declspec(dllimport)`. This would typically be done in a header file which is part of the DLL project file, and would select `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the DLL (unless you are using a .map file), and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling the EXE

In the interest of keeping this simple, I will not stick to that advice.

#### project1_file1.cpp

```
//This is exporting the function from the DLL so that it can be found
__declspec(dllexport) void doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

#### project2_file1.h

```
//This is where we declare the function so our code knows what it is
__declspec(dllimport) void doSomething(); 

typedef struct _myJumpTable_t {
    void (*doSomething)();
}myJumpTable_t;
```

#### project2_file1.c

```
myJumpTable_t myJumpTable = {
    &doSomething //& symbol here is optional, but good practice
};
```

This follows your original code, but note that you can call `doSomething` directly in the EXE once declared. There is no need for the table, unless your other code uses that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I followed your code, however I am getting a warning message treated as a warning:error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated warning C4232: nonstandard extension used : 'doSomething' : address of dllimport 'doSomething' is not static, identity not guaranteed

Comment: I am getting these errors because I am trying to export a C++ function to C. Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1128265 you can add `extern "C"` to the beginning of the function declaration in the C++ code. This will fix up your linkage.
`extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void doSomething();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you building DLL and application that will use this DLL or both projects are just executable modules and you are trying to reuse the code?